# Not able to launch apache apex cli

Tags: apache, hadoop2, apache-apex

I am trying to launch Apache Apex cli but not able to do so.
the document says just type `apex` on command prompt but that says `No command 'apex' found`

Are there some pre steps which i need to perform before start using it?

I have all prerequisites available like, Hadoop, JDK 7, Git and Maven.

Comment: ok ,so how i ran it is, I cloned apex-core from github, navigated to `apex-core/engine/src/main/scripts` and ran the script `apex`

Comment: Use ./apex or add "." (without quotes) into your PATH variable in bash

Comment: @SandeepDeshmukh Added that in the PATH already. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apex` cli is an interface provided to users to interact (launch, monitor, manage ec.) with the Apache Apex Applications. You can find short information about how to build and use it at : [Apex Core git repository](https://github.com/apache/apex-core)

Detailed information can be found here: [Documentation](http://apex.apache.org/docs/apex/apex_cli/)

Comment: Thanks! found it on github url. good to see that i am doing it right way.

Answer (score 0):

Did you build apex-core? If not please run mvn clean install in apex-core directory